# How to apply a different iframe tag depending on the browser/navigator

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have different rendering in my  tag depending on the browser, so what I want is to choose between two iframe tags depending if the browser is IE , or others :

example :

```
<iframe id='Iframe1'></iframe>

<iframe id='Iframe2'></iframe>
```

If (browser **IE** apply **Iframe1** id)
else (apply **Iframe2**)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($.browser.msie == true){
    //Apply frame1
} else {
    //Apply frame2
}
```